# Since FireFox extensions are written in Javascript, how are they able to write to the local disc, which JS proscribes?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

In particular, changes made to the DOM, bookmarks etc. are preserved between sessions. This is true even for HTML files executed from the local disc, without a server. Yet, there is no way in the javascript language to write to anyplace but the screen or a server.

Comment: browser provides you with functions to do that

Comment: JS is just a language. What it can do depends on the underlying implementation. For example, Node.js uses JS and can spawn new processes. In this case, Firefox provides the author with a means of writing to disk.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread thats how